# Oracle odbc connection

Tags: oracle, odbc

I'm trying to connect using different ODBC clients (Advanced query tools and ODBC Query Tool) to my remote Oracle database but every time getting the following error : ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

my connection settings are:

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};dbq=192.168.10.11:1521/TEST_DB;Uid=username;Pwd=password;
```

Could you please explain what is wrong in my connection settings or am I need to configure something else?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/questions/5090/odbc-connector/ 0 answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};
CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server)(PORT=7001))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myDb)));
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your connection string, the Oracle SID or Service Name needs to be specified.  The following are two examples, with one specifying SERVICE_NAME and the other specifying SID:

*Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=199.199.199.199)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dbName)));Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;*

*Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=199.199.199.199)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=dbName)));Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;*

Check your driver documentation to make sure you are including all of the required connection options.  I believe the minimum required details are server, port, SID or SERVICE Name, UID, and PWD.

Tony Hall